# Are tests in rubygems broken intentionally?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, minitest

I've cloned `rubygems` repo (`master` branch), launched `rake` to run tests, and realized that there are a lot of failing specs (22 failures, 41 errors). More than that, sometimes tests running process hangs and doesn't continue until I hit ctrl+c. Am I doing something wrong, or is it intentional behavior?

UPD.

Also, I realized that amount of failures and errors differs from run to run. Tested on ruby 1.9.3 and 2.2.4.

Comment: You probably have environment issues.